# share folder on Win 2003 with XP machine not in the domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, network-share

We have 2003 Sever R2, a folder is shared with many win 7 machines in the domain, I want to share the folder with an xp machine that is not in the domain,

When I open the folder from the xp machine, it doesn't let me enter a username and passwrod, it just tells me I don't have permission to see this folder.

Answer (score 2):

As a first workaround, you can use the commande line: `net use H: \\yourserver\yourshare xxpassxx \USER:yourusername`
or with `\USER:yourdomaine\yourusername`

Next, you can have a look at cached credentials on your Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306541&FR=1&PA=1&SD=HSCH

Comment: when I tried net use m: \\myserver\myshare passwd /u:ourusername
it says that I have to delete any existing mappings to this share,
I used net use delete \\myserver\myshare
and it showed no such mapping???
what is the problem?